# Starting a rake task as daemon

Tags: daemon, rake-task, start-stop-daemon

I'm trying to daemonize a rake task by running the following command (on Ubuntu 12.04)

```
start-stop-daemon -S --pidfile /home/dep/apps/fid/current/tmp/pids/que.pid 
-u dep -d /home/dep/apps/fid/current -b -m
-a "bundle exec rake que:work RAILS_ENV=staging > /home/dep/apps/fid/current/log/que.log 2>&1"
-v
```

The console says

```
Starting bundle exec rake que:work RAILS_ENV=staging > /home/dep/apps/fid/current/log/que.log 2>&1...

Detaching to start bundle exec rake que:work RAILS_ENV=staging > /home/dep/apps/fid/current/log/que.log 2>&1...done.
```

but nothing happen.

the pid file is empty and no log file created.

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get more about the environments (and their differences) when running bundle from your normal environment and running it from start-stop-daemon.
e.g. print all env variables in both cases and adjust accordingly.